# core packages in R 2.XX.Y

Tags: r, package

I wonder how to know which packages are core in `R 2.XX.Y`. Suppose if I install. `R 2.14.1` then which packages will come with this version. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1)  You can look in the sources.

2)  The questions isn't even clear as there are *included* as well as *recommended* libraries.  Most people will understand your question as asking for both sets.

3)  On Debian, we split the install directories so this makes it easy to both answers for question 2):

```
edd@max:~$ ls /usr/lib/R/library/         ## 
base       datasets    lattice  nnet      stats4
boot       foreign     MASS     parallel  survival
class      graphics    Matrix   rpart     tcltk
cluster    grDevices   methods  spatial   tools
codetools  grid        mgcv     splines   utils
compiler   KernSmooth  nlme     stats
```

4) And looking at the sources gives the split between true defaults and Recommended: (and these are softlinks from the versioned tarballs)

```
edd@max:~$ COLUMNS=60 ls ~/src/debian/R/R-2.14.1/src/library/
base      grDevices     methods      splines  tools
compiler  grid          parallel     stats    utils
datasets  Makefile.in   profile      stats4
graphics  Makefile.win  Recommended  tcltk
```

and

```
edd@max:~$ COLUMNS=60 ls ~/src/debian/R/R-2.14.1/src/library/Recommended/
boot_1.3-3.tar.gz         MASS_7.3-16.tar.gz
boot.tgz                  MASS.tgz
class_7.3-3.tar.gz        Matrix_1.0-2.tar.gz
class.tgz                 Matrix.tgz
cluster_1.14.1.tar.gz     mgcv_1.7-12.tar.gz
cluster.tgz               mgcv.tgz
codetools_0.2-8.tar.gz    nlme_3.1-102.tar.gz
codetools.tgz             nlme.tgz
foreign_0.8-48.tar.gz     nnet_7.3-1.tar.gz
foreign.tgz               nnet.tgz
KernSmooth_2.23-7.tar.gz  rpart_3.1-50.tar.gz
KernSmooth.tgz            rpart.tgz
lattice_0.20-0.tar.gz     spatial_7.3-3.tar.gz
lattice.tgz               spatial.tgz
Makefile.in               survival_2.36-10.tar.gz
Makefile.win              survival.tgz
edd@max:~$ COLUMNS=60
```

5)  Lastly, the packages also say this in their DESCRIPTION fields:

```
edd@max:~$ grep -i Recommended /usr/lib/R/library/*/DESCRIPTION
/usr/lib/R/library/boot/DESCRIPTION:Priority: recommended
/usr/lib/R/library/class/DESCRIPTION:Priority: recommended
/usr/lib/R/library/cluster/DESCRIPTION:Priority: recommended
/usr/lib/R/library/codetools/DESCRIPTION:Priority: recommended
/usr/lib/R/library/foreign/DESCRIPTION:Priority: recommended
/usr/lib/R/library/KernSmooth/DESCRIPTION:Priority: recommended
/usr/lib/R/library/lattice/DESCRIPTION:Priority: recommended
/usr/lib/R/library/MASS/DESCRIPTION:Priority: recommended
/usr/lib/R/library/Matrix/DESCRIPTION:Priority: recommended
/usr/lib/R/library/mgcv/DESCRIPTION:Priority: recommended
/usr/lib/R/library/nlme/DESCRIPTION:Priority: recommended
/usr/lib/R/library/nnet/DESCRIPTION:Priority: recommended
/usr/lib/R/library/rpart/DESCRIPTION:Priority: recommended
/usr/lib/R/library/spatial/DESCRIPTION:Priority: recommended
/usr/lib/R/library/survival/DESCRIPTION:Priority: recommended
edd@max:~$
```

and

```
edd@max:~$ grep "Priority: base" /usr/lib/R/library/*/DESCRIPTION
/usr/lib/R/library/base/DESCRIPTION:Priority: base
/usr/lib/R/library/compiler/DESCRIPTION:Priority: base
/usr/lib/R/library/datasets/DESCRIPTION:Priority: base
/usr/lib/R/library/graphics/DESCRIPTION:Priority: base
/usr/lib/R/library/grDevices/DESCRIPTION:Priority: base
/usr/lib/R/library/grid/DESCRIPTION:Priority: base
/usr/lib/R/library/methods/DESCRIPTION:Priority: base
/usr/lib/R/library/parallel/DESCRIPTION:Priority: base
/usr/lib/R/library/splines/DESCRIPTION:Priority: base
/usr/lib/R/library/stats4/DESCRIPTION:Priority: base
/usr/lib/R/library/stats/DESCRIPTION:Priority: base
/usr/lib/R/library/tcltk/DESCRIPTION:Priority: base
/usr/lib/R/library/tools/DESCRIPTION:Priority: base
/usr/lib/R/library/utils/DESCRIPTION:Priority: base
edd@max:~$
```

All those answers are for 2.14.1.

Answer (score 8):

Or you can also use:

```
installed.packages(priority = "base")
```

or look at the FAQ's at:

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Which-add_002don-packages-exist-for-R_003f

Comment: Yes, conditional on you not having removed any :)